# Paypal ios SDK with credit card mexico

Tags: ios, paypal

is possible to use credit cards Mexican, with paypal sdk for ios, and I want to make an app that can make payments with paypal here in mexico

Comment: Would this question not be appropriate to ask at PayPal support site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

As explained at [our github site](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#currencies) and [our developer site](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/#direct-credit-card-payments), at this time our PayPal iOS SDK can process credit card payments only for merchants in Canada, the U.S., and the U.K.

In the coming months we will add support for additional countries. Please check the above sites periodically to check on our progress.

Comment: thank you very much, one last question, if customers have money in your paypal account and this is mexico if you can make the purchase? as I see that there are two mechanisms of payments and the other whether to accept Mexican currency

Comment: Yes. If the customer's PayPal account has a positive balance, then the payment will come from there. Otherwise it will come from their account's default funding source (either bank or credit card). Mexican pesos are one of our supported currencies.

Comment: @Jugs for credit card payments, the limits remain as stated above in my original answer. You can check the two pages linked to in that answer to keep up with any changes.